# Jquery datepicker ranged select doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making a program that incorporates Keith-Wood's jquery datepicker to select range. I cant seem to have it working.

I have input tags that shows the date range and its working fine, it should show those datas with onChange

the problem is how do i pass those 2 datas so i can retrieve it with $_GET?

my input tags is like this

```
<input type="text" id="range2Picker" class="form-control" onChange="getDailyProdReportData(this.value);"><br/>
```

Please help me with any corrections or suggestion

Comment: show us your complete html form - what are you doing in php?

Answer (score 1):

use `var dates = $("#range2Picker").datepick('getDate')` to retrieve values. It returns an array that you can then treat :

```
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) { 
       $.datepick.formatDate(dates[i]);
    }
```

Comment: when he is talking about $_GET it is server side. your code is client side

Comment: Yes @niyou it is client side, to get the values server side jquery offers multiple solutions e.g : `$.get("/my/path", $.param({dates: dates}));`